# How Can I automate dependent test cases with series and parallel mode in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, automation

C - D -E -F

---

B1-B2-B3-B4-B5-B6-B7

---

A1-A2-A3-A4-A5-A6-A7

Hello, I have to automate dependent test cases, In above diagram we can consider as a test cases, I have to create logic that If A1 to A7 will fail then whole suite will fail, but If any A will pass it should go to B and same for CDE and F. But if C and D fails It should go to E. Looing for help please.

Comment: If you are looking in Selenium with Java, then try TestNG with the annotations - 'dependsOnMethods' or 'dependsOnGroups'

Answer (score 0):

I'm also still learning about selenium. But I try to help you, by providing a reference solution to your problem. You can watch [video1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Y6knVutUsI&ab_channel=AutomationStepbyStep) or [video2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WZfh6v53leA&ab_channel=AutomationStepbyStep), good luck.